# Button Click event is getting called for holding event

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have used command binding for the click event of the button. Now i also have a holding event on the button. So whenever i do holding on the button, click is also getting called along with holding event handler. I have tried setting

```
 e.handled = true;
```

but that doesn't work. Any suggestions on why both the events are getting detected. If i use Tapped event instead of command binding, everything work fine. But my requirement is to use command binding for click event.

Edit: Below are some code behind

Code:
xaml :

```
 Button Command={Binding ButtonClicked} Holding="Button_Holding"
```

xaml.cs

```
private void Button_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

ViewModel has the ButtonClicked Command

Comment: Do you specify [ClickMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.buttonbase.clickmode.aspx)?

Comment: There's many ways to bind a command to an event, that's what you should do with the `Tapped` event

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you are trying to achieve? Why do you need to use the `Holding` event?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an Expert in this stuff but i guess that Holding is a bubbling event and ButtonClick is a direct event(If somebody knows that for sure i would love to read a comment)

So your `e.handled = true;` doesn't apply to the ButtonClicked event.
I would say that you have to let your button clicked command know that the hold event was fired first and then ignore that event via the CanExecute method, or whatever you named it, or at least do something like

```
    public void YourButtonClickedMethod()
    { 
         if(SomeObject.IsHoldAllreadyExecuted)
         {
             SomeObject.IsHoldAllreadyExecuted = false; //set it to false for the next run 
         }
         else 
         {
             //DO the stuff you want to
         }

    }
```